# Apply Resolution rule in this formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following formula that i want check the whether it's satisfiable or not

$$\phi\equiv(u_1\vee v_3)\wedge(\neg u_1\vee \neg v_3)\wedge(u_2\vee v_4)\wedge(\neg u_2\vee\neg v_4)$$$$\wedge(u_2\vee v_3)\wedge(\neg u_2\vee \neg v_3)\wedge(u_1\vee v_4) \wedge(\neg u_1\vee \neg v_4)$$

So after applying the resolution rule on $\phi$ such that if i get $\emptyset$ then we conclude it's unsatisfiable, otherwise we conclude $\phi$ is satisfiable.

Now after apply resolution i get
[image]

The question is, at this step can we preceed to apply resolution or not? Or how we can state about satisfiablity of our formula at this step?

Comment: Yes, at this step, we can proceed by unifying $(v_3 \vee \neg v_4)$ and $(\neg v_3 \vee v_4)$ giving the empty clause $\square$ (or $\emptyset$ as denote it), that's all...

Comment: So if we drive cluase $\square$, i think it's a wrong answer, because $\phi$ is satisfiable.

Comment: @JeanMarie You cannot unify $(u_3 \lor \neg u_4)$ and $(\neg u_3 \lor u_4)$ to get the empty clause. You can only resolve on one variable at a time. So, from these two clauses you can get $(u_3 \lor \neg u_3)$ and $(u_4 \lor \neg u_4)$ but that is all you can do (and note that both clauses are tautologous clauses, so that's not anything like a contradiction!)

Comment: @Bram28 You are right ! I had forgotten that basic rule.

Answer (score 1):

Only once you cannot obtain any new clauses can you stop and declare the set of statements to be satisfiable. And there are a bunch more resolutions you can (and therefore should) perform:

$(u_1 \lor u_3)$ resolves with $(\neg u_1 \lor \neg u_3)$ to get $(u_1 \lor \neg u_1)$

$(u_1 \lor u_3)$ resolves with $(\neg u_1 \lor \neg u_3)$ to get $(u_3 \lor \neg u_3)$

$(u_2 \lor u_3)$ resolves with $(\neg u_1 \lor \neg u_3)$ to get $(u_2 \lor \neg u_1)$

....

but yes, at some point you will find that there are no more new clauses that you can obtain, and then (and only then) you can stop.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts about this question.

First of all, I convert letters $v$ into letters $u$ for the sake of simplification. I give the following names:

$$\varphi := \underbrace{(u_1\vee u_3)}_{E_{13}}\wedge \underbrace{(\neg u_1\vee \neg u_3)}_{F_{13}}\wedge \underbrace{(u_2\vee u_4)}_{E_{24}}\wedge\underbrace{(\neg u_2\vee\neg u_4)}_{F_{24}}\wedge \underbrace{(u_2\vee u_3)}_{E_{23}}\wedge\underbrace{(\neg u_2\vee \neg u_3)}_{F_{23}}\wedge\underbrace{(u_1\vee u_4)}_{E_{14}} \wedge\underbrace{(\neg u_1\vee \neg u_4)}_{F_{14}}\tag{1}$$

Remark: Grouping each disjunction $E_{ij}$ with its neighbour $F_{ij}$, we can write $\varphi$ in the following way :

$$(u_1 \lor\!\!\lor \ u_3)\wedge(u_2 \lor\!\!\lor \ u_4) \wedge(u_2 \lor\!\!\lor \ u_3)\wedge(u_1 \lor\!\!\lor \ u_4)\tag{2}$$

where $\lor\!\!\lor$ stands for the "exclusive or".

2. I have had the idea to build a truth table to see the satisfiability of $\varphi$:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
u_1&u_2&u_3&u_4&V\\
\hline
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&\color{red}{1}\\
0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&0\\
\hline\end{array}$$

wich means (see the red "ones") in particular that

$\varphi$ is satisfiable in two ways.

3. Now that we have spotted the lines giving a true result, let us return to the logic of order $0$ by considering the corresponding conjunctions:

$$\begin{cases}\alpha&:=&\neg u_1 \wedge \neg u_2 \wedge u_3 \wedge u_4\\ \beta&:=&u_1 \wedge u_2 \wedge \neg u_3 \wedge \neg u_4\end{cases}$$

Let us prove that $$\varphi \vdash \alpha, \beta$$ by showing that the set of clauses:

$$\{\varphi, \neg \alpha, \neg \beta \}$$ obtained by adjoining to $\varphi$, the **negation of the conclusions**

$$\begin{cases}\neg \alpha&=&u_1 \vee u_2 \vee \neg u_3 \vee \neg u_4 \\
\neg \beta&=&\neg u_1 \vee \neg u_2 \vee u_3 \vee  u_4 \end{cases}$$

is non satisfiable by using the resolution method.

For example, unifying $\neg \alpha$ and $F_{24}$ we get $\gamma:=\neg u_1 \vee \neg u_2 \vee u_3$. Unifying $\gamma$ with $E_{23}$, we get $\delta:=\neg u_1 \vee u_3$.

In a parallel way, unifying $\neg \beta$ and $F_{24}$ we get $\epsilon:=u_1 \vee \neg u_3 \vee \neg u_4$ ; then unifying $\epsilon$ and $F_{14}$, we get $\zeta:=\neg u_3 \vee \neg u_4$ ; unifying $\zeta$ and $E_{14}$, we get $\eta:=u_1 \vee \neg u_3$. etc... etc... and finally (I have done the computations...), we get **$u_1$ and $\neg u_3$**.

Unifying now $\delta$ found above with $u_1$ gives $u_3$, and unifying $u_3$ with $\neg u_3$ gives the $\square$ clause !